# How can I start spring boot application in docker with profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I have a simple spring-boot project:

```
-resources
 -application.yaml
 -application-test.yaml
```

And I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ADD micro-boot.jar micro-boot.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=test" "-jar","/micro-boot.jar"]
```

1) I build image - `C:\micro-boot>docker build -f Dockerfile -t micro-boot .`

2) show all images - `C:\micro-boot>docker image ls -a`

```
micro-boot   latest  ccc9a75ebc24  4 seconds ago 112MB
```

3) try to start `C:\micro-boot>docker image ls -a`

And I get an error:

```
/bin/sh: [java,-Dspring.profiles.active=test: not found
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: You should passing spring.profiles.active by docker run command or docker-compose which will increase flexibility. Ex: `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test"`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's a typo here

`ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=test" comma missing here "-jar","/micro-boot.jar"`]

Answer (score 126):

We have 3 ways:

**1. Passing Spring Profile in a Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
...
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.profiles.active=test","-jar","app.jar"]
```

**2. Passing Spring Profile in Docker run**

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test" --name my-app:latest
```

**3. Passing Spring Profile in DockerCompose**

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  my-app:
     image: my-app:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:8080" 
     environment:
       - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test"
```

Comment: imagine you have 4 environments dev sys staging prod, using kubernetes and dynamically you deploy the containers, you can't have different  cmd like you ve shown "docker run", in this way you must have a env var of the cluster env to be used inside the docker file like $PROFILE

Comment: @TiagoMedici you right, but it broad out of scope of the question. I will update answer for Kubernetes env. Thank you for your attention

Comment: "2. Passing Spring Profile in Docker run" rocks!