# How to choose correct profile on different environments for Docker and Docker-Compose?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, application.properties

Actually I have checked some questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55752013/how-can-i-start-spring-boot-application-in-docker-with-profile)

What I do not understand is; if I change my docker-compose.yml and add profile to it then should I leave the Dockerfile without profile ?
For example my docker-compose file:

```
backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build: ./backend
    restart: always
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 15
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DbPass3008
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=DbPass3008
      - MYSQL_USER=DbUser
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

And I will add:

```
environment:
       - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test
```

As far as I understand I need to put 3 different compose file and run them with -f parameter for different environments like:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-local/test/prod up -d
```

But my question is that my Dockerfile is already specifying profile as:

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
ADD ./target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=TEST", "backend.jar"]
```

So how should I change this **Dockerfile**? Even if I create 3-4 different compose file, they are all using same **Dockerfile**. Should I create different Dockerfiles too (seems ridicilous) but what is the correct way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add a `java -Dspring.profiles.active=...` command-line option; Spring will recognize the runtime `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment variable on its own.  That means all of your environments can use the same image (which is generally a good practice).

Compose can also [expand host environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) in some contexts, so you may be able to use a single Compose file with environment-variable references

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${ENVIRONMENT:-dev}
```

```bash
ENVIRONMENT=test docker-compose up -d
```

I tend to discourage putting environment-specific settings in a `src/main/resources/*.yml` file, since it means you need to recompile the application jar file whenever you deploy to a new environment.  Another possibility is to set most Spring properties as environment variables, and then use [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) to include environment-specific settings.  The one downside here is that you need multiple `docker-compose -f` options and you need to repeat them on *every* `docker-compose` invocation.